# Value в Contact Form 7

Tags: wordpress, email

Здравствуйте!
Я столкнулся с небольшой проблемой в плагине **Contact Form 7** для **WordPress**.

Изначально тексты со словами **"email"**, **"ваше сообщение"** и т.п. были отдельно от полей для ввода информации.
Я видоизменил код, получилось вместо:

```
<p>Ваш E-Mail<br />
[email* your-email] </p>
```

Вот это:

```
<p><span class="wpcf7-form-control-wrap email"><input type="text" name="email" value="Ваш email" onfocus="if (this.value == 'Ваш email') {this.value = '';}" onblur="if (this.value == '') {this.value = 'Ваш email';}" id="email-txt" class="wpcf7-form-control wpcf7-text wpcf7-email wpcf7-validates-as-required wpcf7-validates-as-email" size="40" /></span></p>
```

Теперь при нажатии на поле **value='Ваш email'** становится пустым, а если поле теряет фокус и пользователь ничего не ввёл, то **value** снова принимает своё предыдущее значение.

***Вопрос:*** Contact Form 7 проверяет **корректность** введённого email.
После того, как я изменил код, проверка перестала работать. Теперь можно спокойно отправлять сообщения, где будет написано *Email: Ваш email.*

Как исправить? Прошу прощения за длинный вопрос, очень нужна помощь!

Спасибо!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Возможно, что кому-нибудь пригодится ответ.

Нужно отредактировать файл **"text.php"** в папке **"модули"**.
Находим строчку:

```
$html = '<input type="text" name="' . $name . '" value="' . esc_attr( $value ) . '"' . $atts . ' />';
```

**И редактируем на:**

```
$html = '<input type="text" name="' . $name . '" value="' . esc_attr( $value ) . '"' . $atts . ' onfocus="if(this.value==\'';

$html = $html . esc_attr( $value ) . '\') this.value=\'\';" onblur="if(this.value==\'\') this.value=\'' . esc_attr( $value ) . '\';" />';
```

**Теперь поле вида:**

```
<p>Ваш E-Mail<br />
[email* your-email] </p>
```

**будет работать как и задумывалось.**

Answer (score 2):

Там галочка есть....

[text* your-name id:name class:form-control **placeholder** "Николай"]

Вот так должно быть....

value - это значение

а placeholder - это автозаполнитель....

Answer (score 0):

А почему бы не использовать параметр watermark?

```
<p>Ваш E-Mail<br />
[email* your-email watermark "Ваш email"] </p>
```

Ведь если менять код плагина, то при его обновлении все изменения будут потеряны.

Comment: Здравствуйте!
Watermark не работает. Я пробовал использовать его как до написания вопроса, так и сейчас, чтобы быть уверенным в ответе.
Если я не прав, поправьте.

Comment: В CF7 watermark замечательно работает.
Проверьте в коде сгенерированной страницы у тега input наличие классов wpcf7-use-title-as-watermark и watermark, а также атрибута title с заполненным значением.
Если все это присутствует, то скорее всего не отрабатывает скрипт contact-form-7/includes/js/scripts.js
Т.е. нужно искать и устранять конфликт скриптов.